# How can I configure the xml config filename used by the Spring DispatcherServlet?

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, config

The documentation states that by default, the (WebApplication?) config file of the DispatcherServlet is found by appending "-servlet.xml" to the servlet-name, but I need to configure the name of this file explicitly. The Spring documentation of course does not describe how *not* to use the default.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/filename.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Isn't that the application context location? Our current config has this set to an empty value (I don't know why that was done). What I ended up doing is configured the ContextLoaderListener to load up the explicit WebApplicationContext file (who's name is dependent on an environment variable) and then use the contextAttribute parameter with a value of "org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT" to include (I assume) everything loaded by the ContextLoaderListener. Can you see any disadvantages to that?

Comment: full example : [web.xml](https://gist.github.com/908777). As you can see it's not the application context location. The application context location is defined on the top